# How to use an inner record field as message key in Fluent Bit Kafka output?

Tags: apache-kafka, fluent-bit

With the config below:

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/containers/*.log
    multiline.parser docker, cri
    Tag kube.*
    Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB
    Skip_Long_Lines On

[FILTER]
    Name kubernetes
    Match kube.*
    Merge_Log On
    Keep_Log Off
    K8S-Logging.Parser On
    K8S-Logging.Exclude On

[OUTPUT]
    Name kafka
    Match kube.*
    Brokers <some-broker>
    Topics <some-topic>
```

FluentBit sends container logs to Kafka with the message value below:

```
{
   "@timestamp":1670628155.720578,
   "log":"<some-container-log>",
   "stream":"stdout",
   "time":"2022-12-09T23:22:35.720578536Z",
   "kubernetes":{
      "pod_name":"<...>",
      "namespace_name":"<...>",
      "pod_id":"<...>",
      "annotations":{ <...> },
      "host":"<...>",
      "container_name":"<...>",
      "docker_id":"<...>",
      "container_hash":"<...>",
      "container_image":"<...>"
   }
}
```

Now I want this message to have key. When added below line to Kafka output config:

```
Message_Key_Field stream
```

I see that all messages have key `stdout`, which is the value for `stream` key in the message value. However, when I want to use a field from `"kubernetes"` in the JSON, say `"pod_name"`, none of below worked and messages ended up with empty key:

```
- Message_Key_Field kubernetes.pod_id
- Message_Key_Field kubernetes['pod_id']
- Message_Key_Field $kubernetes['pod_id']
```

What is the correct syntax to refer to an inner JSON value of the record from output plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It should be your third option. Isn't that working for you?
What does your full config look like?